# Get text from option instead of value

Tags: jquery

Say I have:

```
<option value="1">TEXTHERE</option>
```

I tried this:

```
value = $('#select-dropdown:selected').text();
```

But I get nothing. If I use `.val()` I get 1. What I really want is the "TEXTHERE" in this case (I need the `1` in other places).

How do I get the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the word `option` after the select-list id.

It should be something like:

```
$( "#select-dropdown option:selected" ).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
value = $('select option:selected').html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekdxmnwv/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
text = $("option[value='1']").text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/owL9c1gt/

Answer (score 0):

```
value = $('#select-dropdown option:selected').text();

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be
value = $('#select-dropdown option:selected').text();